# Why roc_curve() function reversed the values of FPR and TPR?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I want to plot the ROC curve using python. I using `roc_curve()` function. I passed binary labels and the scores as input along with the `pos_label = 1`. When I plot fpr and tpr, the plot seems to reverse. I provided the same inputs to MedCalc, and it is giving me the correct ROC curve. I have attached the plots using python and Medcalc with this query. I seem like `roc_curve()` is not providing correct values for fpr and tpr, they look like revered.

I used the following code for generating roc in python.

```
    labels = GT[:,0]
    scores = Test_CCVRC[:, 0]
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(labels,scores,pos_label = 1)
    a1 = auc(fpr, tpr)
    plt.plot(fpr,tpr)
    plt.show()
```

Does anyone know why this happening?
Following is my data: (i) labels and (ii) scores

```
    labels  scores
0   0.235
0   0.429
0   0.119
0   0.236
0   0.378
0   0.147
1   0.036
0   0.27
0   0.041
1   0.496
0   0.57
1   0.027
0   0.289
0   0.33
1   0.129
1   0.334
0   0.364
0   0.139
1   0.036
1   0.139
0   0.095
1   0.208
1   0.507
0   0.63
1   0.064
0   0.429
1   0.048
1   0.072
1   0.043
1   0.045
0   0.192
0   0.217
0   0.274
1   0.04
0   0.513
0   0.707
1   0.397
0   0.837
0   0.139
1   0.051
0   0.258
0   0.258
0   0.174
0   0.386
0   0.307
0   0.151
0   0.387
0   0.277
0   0.513
1   0.062
0   0.374
0   0.258
1   0.224
0   0.411
0   0.095
0   0.401
0   0.043
0   0.045
1   0.722
0   0.415
1   0.304
0   0.243
1   0.051
1   0.019
1   0.213
1   0.038
0   0.27
0   0.106
0   0.123
0   0.429
0   0.824
0   0.153
0   0.457
0   0.614
0   0.457
0   0.401
0   0.215
0   0.029
0   0.087
0   0.151
0   0.135
0   0.043
0   0.089
0   0.067
0   0.291
0   0.386
0   0.072
0   0.308
0   0.692
0   0.202
0   0.175
0   0.03
0   0.16
0   0.314
0   0.081
0   0.06
0   0.334
0   0.032
0   0.812
0   0.245
0   0.471
0   0.118
0   0.214
0   0.347
0   0.401
0   0.048
0   0.347
0   0.253
1   0.034
0   0.222
0   0.374
0   0.334
1   0.034
1   0.168
1   0.071
0   0.188
0   0.63
1   0.145
0   0.556
0   0.564
1   0.152
1   0.095
1   0.022
1   0.111
1   0.067
1   0.179
1   0.118
1   0.525
1   0.075
1   0.028
0   0.415
1   0.021
0   0.611
1   0.1
0   0.115
1   0.048
1   0.071
0   0.043
1   0.023
1   0.068
1   0.032
1   0.089
1   0.235
1   0.537
0   0.216
0   0.852
0   0.048
0   0.047
0   0.39
0   0.258
0   0.053
0   0.308
0   0.165
0   0.09
0   0.163
0   0.075
0   0.387
0   0.211
0   0.224
0   0.075
0   0.479
0   0.581
0   0.126
0   0.261
0   0.116
0   0.118
0   0.462
0   0.191
0   0.205
0   0.707
0   0.443
0   0.2
0   0.321
0   0.677
0   0.646
0   0.581
0   0.614
0   0.087
0   0.047
0   0.2
0   0.205
0   0.477
0   0.153
0   0.334
0   0.321
0   0.432
0   0.141
0   0.223
0   0.135
0   0.263
0   0.265
0   0.373
0   0.387
0   0.135
0   0.095
0   0.123836
0   0.203306
0   0.0599974
0   0.215808
0   0.636168
0   0.156546
0   0.499754
0   0.0947688
0   0.299356
1   0.025
1   0.071
1   0.236
1   0.155
1   0.429
1   0.564
1   0.07
1   0.378
1   0.026
1   0.191
1   0.234
1   0.234
0   0.294
1   0.045
1   0.041
0   0.135
0   0.135
0   0.097
0   0.395
1   0.045
1   0.099
0   0.347
0   0.485
0   0.026
0   0.707
0   0.611
1   0.042
0   0.151
1   0.111
0   0.39
0   0.079
1   0.048
1   0.214
0   0.235
0   0.235
0   0.261
0   0.304
0   0.066
0   0.021
0   0.522
0   0.415
0   0.09
1   0.049
0   0.63
0   0.358
1   0.089
0   0.02
1   0.305
1   0.081
1   0.107
0   0.14
0   0.374
0   0.146
0   0.146
0   0.101
0   0.34
0   0.132
0   0.085
0   0.295
0   0.0786545
0   0.516501
0   0.514767
0   0.22093
0   0.196636
0   0.216631
0   0.126442
0   0.372007
0   0.245771
0   0.388313
0   0.433006
0   0.0950429
0   0.130623
0   0.210527
0   0.551082
0   0.0383115
0   0.352262
0   0.594012
0   0.0481855
0   0.616439
0   0.308471
0   0.119363
0   0.659183
0   0.625898
0   0.22617
0   0.457257
0   0.307292
0   0.29276
0   0.235792
0   0.224144
0   0.369317
0   0.498693
0   0.433887
0   0.617303
0   0.496014
0   0.308688
0   0.364952
0   0.459557
0   0.289455
0   0.167997
0   0.455669
0   0.390504
0   0.135362
0   0.147
0   0.373
0   0.1
0   0.032
1   0.227
0   0.316
0   0.128
0   0.165
1   0.196
1   0.071
0   0.583
0   0.093
0   0.27
0   0.213
0   0.125
0   0.196
0   0.289
0   0.162
0   0.254
0   0.401
0   0.369
1   0.122
0   0.263
0   0.812
0   0.253
1   0.015
1   0.219
0   0.095
0   0.079
0   0.258
0   0.069
1   0.116
1   0.275
1   0.319
1   0.401
1   0.076
1   0.044
1   0.036
1   0.062
1   0.045
1   0.156
1   0.181
1   0.103
1   0.051
1   0.374
1   0.347
1   0.269
1   0.25
1   0.168
1   0.237
0   0.319211
0   0.143967
0   0.469586
0   0.374986
0   0.0975702
0   0.281074
0   0.113676
0   0.340785
0   0.572822
0   0.101255
0   0.621299
0   0.346375
0   0.56386
0   0.586318
0   0.60373
0   0.0901153
0   0.11667
0   0.20222
0   0.585933
0   0.381463
0   0.338894
0   0.211144
0   0.555193
0   0.724234
0   0.344827
0   0.456181
0   0.0714731
0   0.183835
0   0.24842
0   0.0521189
0   0.506046
0   0.152593
0   0.537725
0   0.176324
0   0.113831
0   0.243366
0   0.354688
0   0.272897
0   0.149464
0   0.265145
0   0.385323
0   0.1382
0   0.534598
0   0.651152
0   0.152536
0   0.307042
0   0.414642
0   0.208011
0   0.514448
0   0.280359
0   0.140093
0   0.508994
0   0.474
0   0.581
0   0.417
0   0.079
0   0.041
0   0.579
0   0.487
0   0.532
0   0.255
0   0.556
0   0.191
0   0.215
0   0.27
0   0.559
0   0.069
0   0.75
0   0.321
0   0.455
0   0.153
0   0.076
0   0.423
0   0.334
0   0.27
0   0.457
0   0.42
1   0.149
1   0.084
1   0.118
1   0.204
1   0.352
1   0.27
1   0.028
1   0.051
1   0.334
1   0.064
1   0.364
1   0.146
1   0.15
1   0.128
1   0.677
1   0.087
1   0.113
1   0.496
1   0.27
1   0.087
1   0.069
1   0.048
1   0.147
1   0.581
1   0.25
0   0.499039
0   0.160928
0   0.300877
0   0.441945
0   0.457
0   0.308663
0   0.134503
0   0.329045
0   0.0978461
0   0.34092
0   0.182607
0   0.210408
0   0.101455
0   0.387889
0   0.21298
0   0.2772
0   0.108788
0   0.0916171
0   0.256354
0   0.609318
0   0.517059
0   0.238948
0   0.107597
0   0.141816
0   0.288725
0   0.104569
0   0.465725
0   0.61839
0   0.333287
0   0.30421
0   0.352555
0   0.0990847
0   0.122333
0   0.462303
0   0.261282
0   0.551918
0   0.130356
0   0.092168
0   0.147923
0   0.384127
0   0.307815
0   0.636982
0   0.455577
0   0.320379
0   0.391365
0   0.41054
0   0.0883434
0   0.0718396
0   0.275106
0   0.634415
0   0.403165
0   0.182067
0   0.064
0   0.103
0   0.076
0   0.112
0   0.514
0   0.677
0   0.298
0   0.513
0   0.152
0   0.179
0   0.485
0   0.57
0   0.242
0   0.084
0   0.496
0   0.374
0   0.472
0   0.513
0   0.016
0   0.162
0   0.337
0   0.308
0   0.581
0   0.443
0   0.27
0   0.316
1   0.01
1   0.047
1   0.314
1   0.053
1   0.53
1   0.152
1   0.514
1   0.217
1   0.462
1   0.359
1   0.453
1   0.415
1   0.321
1   0.327
1   0.352
1   0.066
1   0.0731183
1   0.038658
1   0.246056
1   0.0367594
1   0.250052
1   0.045
1   0.0213815
1   0.134981
1   0.110564
1   0.280861
0   0.171486
0   0.213024
0   0.494228
0   0.227073
0   0.292089
0   0.42622
0   0.08547
0   0.329002
0   0.238219
0   0.139873
0   0.140293
0   0.129252
0   0.673
0   0.18236
0   0.0863466
0   0.2965
0   0.153781
0   0.11698
0   0.147802
0   0.255003
0   0.171924
0   0.395025
0   0.426824
0   0.0725817
0   0.0922318
0   0.321184
0   0.160056
0   0.465388
0   0.0830692
0   0.138164
0   0.66248
0   0.28919
0   0.127184
0   0.672319
0   0.273915
0   0.274922
0   0.199821
0   0.313002
0   0.245132
0   0.130502
0   0.134067
0   0.318106
0   0.101821
0   0.379408
0   0.633172
0   0.188568
0   0.576171
0   0.167011
0   0.108279
0   0.269696
0   0.447
0   0.224
0   0.297
0   0.172
0   0.053
0   0.056
0   0.659
0   0.04
0   0.088
0   0.307
0   0.18
0   0.53
0   0.358
0   0.229
0   0.214
0   0.733
0   0.678
0   0.171
0   0.429
0   0.336
0   0.374
0   0.707
0   0.095
0   0.581
0   0.1
0   0.556
1   0.527863
1   0.0954031
1   0.0917822
1   0.180745
1   0.127418
1   0.331459
1   0.192092
1   0.134105
1   0.299971
1   0.151696
1   0.198835
1   0.0586442
1   0.170819
1   0.0443812
1   0.114581
1   0.0396201
1   0.0920748
1   0.128747
1   0.248526
1   0.0745064
1   0.0498816
1   0.030139
1   0.0315029
1   0.561851
1   0.248531
1   0.048036
0   0.0934189
0   0.260005
0   0.138785
0   0.222089
0   0.275293
0   0.376301
0   0.120048
0   0.142064
0   0.140965
0   0.1977
0   0.0327019
0   0.256466
0   0.380596
0   0.130867
0   0.27045
0   0.186554
0   0.0417732
0   0.166857
0   0.138238
0   0.294624
0   0.0640384
0   0.262783
0   0.159907
0   0.114941
0   0.373715
0   0.369551
0   0.610447
0   0.161292
0   0.18475
0   0.188318
0   0.227243
0   0.266968
0   0.317873
0   0.18678
0   0.159872
0   0.464529
0   0.0683459
0   0.17457
0   0.124066
0   0.134363
0   0.105031
0   0.258503
0   0.50318
0   0.398564
0   0.253605
0   0.0924549
0   0.459214
0   0.37779
0   0.423409
0   0.258992
0   0.099
0   0.237
0   0.471
0   0.329
0   0.206
0   0.04
0   0.313
0   0.097
0   0.095
0   0.128
0   0.447
0   0.471
0   0.085
0   0.145
0   0.457
0   0.192
0   0.071
0   0.497
0   0.06
0   0.113
0   0.072
0   0.265
0   0.161
0   0.14
0   0.42
0   0.235
1   0.0380548
1   0.163722
1   0.236318
1   0.181422
1   0.0564229
1   0.440888
1   0.163106
1   0.0305579
1   0.234902
1   0.0231549
1   0.499566
1   0.0489939
1   0.151815
1   0.110802
1   0.161408
1   0.357252
1   0.109732
1   0.147189
1   0.0457421
1   0.0506764
1   0.368286
1   0.225774
1   0.141402
1   0.0613732
1   0.0584686
1   0.0732126
0   0.074218
0   0.414306
0   0.357649
0   0.0787495
0   0.133315
0   0.402939
0   0.458143
0   0.513628
0   0.369206
0   0.114458
0   0.321146
0   0.301131
0   0.035064
0   0.383734
0   0.376885
0   0.195077
0   0.248111
0   0.159997
0   0.190945
0   0.390668
0   0.220731
0   0.210318
0   0.484851
0   0.0783254
0   0.242972
0   0.116302
0   0.336361
0   0.119856
0   0.630317
0   0.771343
0   0.773017
0   0.468167
0   0.107114
0   0.152301
0   0.460471
0   0.187254
0   0.30811
0   0.171004
0   0.381257
0   0.325415
0   0.371989
0   0.156949
0   0.105421
0   0.165772
0   0.105301
0   0.289966
0   0.24644
0   0.623244
0   0.376608
0   0.153546
0   0.095
0   0.471
0   0.069
0   0.595
0   0.499
0   0.13
0   0.098
0   0.243
0   0.556
0   0.13
0   0.346
0   0.597
0   0.051
0   0.295
0   0.789
0   0.344
0   0.485
0   0.471
0   0.059
0   0.676
0   0.528
0   0.581
0   0.083
0   0.53
0   0.513
0   0.462
1   0.279584
1   0.0829043
1   0.0820136
1   0.165237
1   0.41255
1   0.49425
1   0.0323492
1   0.236546
1   0.0440709
1   0.110593
1   0.1594
1   0.0669509
1   0.0544058
1   0.0690369
1   0.0843828
1   0.0734309
1   0.0552424
1   0.0846833
1   0.1358
1   0.0869965
1   0.345526
1   0.087353
1   0.0484685
1   0.640354
1   0.0382975
1   0.317377
0   0.302771
0   0.409004
0   0.134815
0   0.249468
0   0.148964
0   0.525877
0   0.357133
0   0.296977
0   0.532913
0   0.406251
0   0.229567
0   0.121607
0   0.10691
0   0.173965
0   0.0352168
0   0.228672
0   0.0387207
0   0.094927
0   0.388997
0   0.615013
0   0.484827
0   0.193353
0   0.187652
0   0.399581
0   0.288581
0   0.422332
0   0.235464
0   0.361755
0   0.165823
0   0.382025
0   0.454439
0   0.117501
0   0.583703
0   0.79541
0   0.270634
0   0.0929322
0   0.622777
0   0.389252
0   0.101031
0   0.129959
0   0.409462
0   0.340361
0   0.207414
0   0.315491
0   0.467678
0   0.134645
0   0.0591025
0   0.329735
0   0.22174
0   0.61266
0   0.246
0   0.059
0   0.159
0   0.305
0   0.401
0   0.367
0   0.226
0   0.305
0   0.462
0   0.455
0   0.226
0   0.579
0   0.36
0   0.662
0   0.707
0   0.536
0   0.303
0   0.095
0   0.083
0   0.235
0   0.429
0   0.472
0   0.487
0   0.477
0   0.286
0   0.084
1   0.0783283
1   0.176506
1   0.04887
1   0.0869539
1   0.087
1   0.186845
1   0.148847
1   0.0407017
1   0.0773003
1   0.322769
1   0.133622
1   0.0486399
1   0.165149
1   0.0631825
1   0.526216
1   0.270059
1   0.171065
1   0.21778
1   0.504645
1   0.234726
1   0.0407718
1   0.0211361
1   0.123052
1   0.51742
1   0.332244
1   0.010902
0   0.147953
0   0.421645
0   0.138002
0   0.0561383
0   0.457
0   0.142435
0   0.0415891
0   0.457
0   0.182079
0   0.441678
0   0.116248
0   0.245537
0   0.119357
0   0.202454
0   0.338576
0   0.075427
0   0.184856
0   0.242849
0   0.236672
0   0.240706
0   0.0335897
0   0.0631483
0   0.301717
0   0.171068
0   0.102062
0   0.470175
0   0.616654
0   0.656733
0   0.221006
0   0.459261
0   0.150705
0   0.320793
0   0.369289
0   0.239808
0   0.2786
0   0.517987
0   0.463495
0   0.685939
0   0.260091
0   0.249229
0   0.663916
0   0.134539
0   0.363797
0   0.299316
0   0.154111
0   0.254985
0   0.195693
0   0.537799
0   0.601339
0   0.422757
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Currently your code can't be run, because the data is missing.

Comment: I am trying to upload the data, which is in excel file. Do you know how to do that

Comment: Hi, I have added my data (i) labels and (ii) scores.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the positions of `fpr` and `tpr` in your `auc()` method:

```
labels = label_list
scores = data_list
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(labels,scores,pos_label = 1)
a1 = auc(tpr,fpr)
plt.plot(tpr,fpr)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

Complete code:

```
data = """0   0.235
0   0.429
0   0.119
0   0.236
0   0.378
0   0.147
1   0.036
0   0.27
0   0.041
1   0.496
0   0.57
1   0.027
0   0.289
0   0.33
1   0.129
1   0.334
0   0.364
0   0.139
1   0.036
1   0.139
0   0.095
1   0.208
1   0.507
0   0.63
1   0.064
0   0.429
1   0.048
1   0.072
1   0.043
1   0.045
0   0.192
0   0.217
0   0.274
1   0.04
0   0.513
0   0.707
1   0.397
0   0.837
0   0.139
1   0.051
0   0.258
0   0.258
0   0.174
0   0.386
0   0.307
0   0.151
0   0.387
0   0.277
0   0.513
1   0.062
0   0.374
0   0.258
1   0.224
0   0.411
0   0.095
0   0.401
0   0.043
0   0.045
1   0.722
0   0.415
1   0.304
0   0.243
1   0.051
1   0.019
1   0.213
1   0.038
0   0.27
0   0.106
0   0.123
0   0.429
0   0.824
0   0.153
0   0.457
0   0.614
0   0.457
0   0.401
0   0.215
0   0.029
0   0.087
0   0.151
0   0.135
0   0.043
0   0.089
0   0.067
0   0.291
0   0.386
0   0.072
0   0.308
0   0.692
0   0.202
0   0.175
0   0.03
0   0.16
0   0.314
0   0.081
0   0.06
0   0.334
0   0.032
0   0.812
0   0.245
0   0.471
0   0.118
0   0.214
0   0.347
0   0.401
0   0.048
0   0.347
0   0.253
1   0.034
0   0.222
0   0.374
0   0.334
1   0.034
1   0.168
1   0.071
0   0.188
0   0.63
1   0.145
0   0.556
0   0.564
1   0.152
1   0.095
1   0.022
1   0.111
1   0.067
1   0.179
1   0.118
1   0.525
1   0.075
1   0.028
0   0.415
1   0.021
0   0.611
1   0.1
0   0.115
1   0.048
1   0.071
0   0.043
1   0.023
1   0.068
1   0.032
1   0.089
1   0.235
1   0.537
0   0.216
0   0.852
0   0.048
0   0.047
0   0.39
0   0.258
0   0.053
0   0.308
0   0.165
0   0.09
0   0.163
0   0.075
0   0.387
0   0.211
0   0.224
0   0.075
0   0.479
0   0.581
0   0.126
0   0.261
0   0.116
0   0.118
0   0.462
0   0.191
0   0.205
0   0.707
0   0.443
0   0.2
0   0.321
0   0.677
0   0.646
0   0.581
0   0.614
0   0.087
0   0.047
0   0.2
0   0.205
0   0.477
0   0.153
0   0.334
0   0.321
0   0.432
0   0.141
0   0.223
0   0.135
0   0.263
0   0.265
0   0.373
0   0.387
0   0.135
0   0.095
0   0.123836
0   0.203306
0   0.0599974
0   0.215808
0   0.636168
0   0.156546
0   0.499754
0   0.0947688
0   0.299356
1   0.025
1   0.071
1   0.236
1   0.155
1   0.429
1   0.564
1   0.07
1   0.378
1   0.026
1   0.191
1   0.234
1   0.234
0   0.294
1   0.045
1   0.041
0   0.135
0   0.135
0   0.097
0   0.395
1   0.045
1   0.099
0   0.347
0   0.485
0   0.026
0   0.707
0   0.611
1   0.042
0   0.151
1   0.111
0   0.39
0   0.079
1   0.048
1   0.214
0   0.235
0   0.235
0   0.261
0   0.304
0   0.066
0   0.021
0   0.522
0   0.415
0   0.09
1   0.049
0   0.63
0   0.358
1   0.089
0   0.02
1   0.305
1   0.081
1   0.107
0   0.14
0   0.374
0   0.146
0   0.146
0   0.101
0   0.34
0   0.132
0   0.085
0   0.295
0   0.0786545
0   0.516501
0   0.514767
0   0.22093
0   0.196636
0   0.216631
0   0.126442
0   0.372007
0   0.245771
0   0.388313
0   0.433006
0   0.0950429
0   0.130623
0   0.210527
0   0.551082
0   0.0383115
0   0.352262
0   0.594012
0   0.0481855
0   0.616439
0   0.308471
0   0.119363
0   0.659183
0   0.625898
0   0.22617
0   0.457257
0   0.307292
0   0.29276
0   0.235792
0   0.224144
0   0.369317
0   0.498693
0   0.433887
0   0.617303
0   0.496014
0   0.308688
0   0.364952
0   0.459557
0   0.289455
0   0.167997
0   0.455669
0   0.390504
0   0.135362
0   0.147
0   0.373
0   0.1
0   0.032
1   0.227
0   0.316
0   0.128
0   0.165
1   0.196
1   0.071
0   0.583
0   0.093
0   0.27
0   0.213
0   0.125
0   0.196
0   0.289
0   0.162
0   0.254
0   0.401
0   0.369
1   0.122
0   0.263
0   0.812
0   0.253
1   0.015
1   0.219
0   0.095
0   0.079
0   0.258
0   0.069
1   0.116
1   0.275
1   0.319
1   0.401
1   0.076
1   0.044
1   0.036
1   0.062
1   0.045
1   0.156
1   0.181
1   0.103
1   0.051
1   0.374
1   0.347
1   0.269
1   0.25
1   0.168
1   0.237
0   0.319211
0   0.143967
0   0.469586
0   0.374986
0   0.0975702
0   0.281074
0   0.113676
0   0.340785
0   0.572822
0   0.101255
0   0.621299
0   0.346375
0   0.56386
0   0.586318
0   0.60373
0   0.0901153
0   0.11667
0   0.20222
0   0.585933
0   0.381463
0   0.338894
0   0.211144
0   0.555193
0   0.724234
0   0.344827
0   0.456181
0   0.0714731
0   0.183835
0   0.24842
0   0.0521189
0   0.506046
0   0.152593
0   0.537725
0   0.176324
0   0.113831
0   0.243366
0   0.354688
0   0.272897
0   0.149464
0   0.265145
0   0.385323
0   0.1382
0   0.534598
0   0.651152
0   0.152536
0   0.307042
0   0.414642
0   0.208011
0   0.514448
0   0.280359
0   0.140093
0   0.508994
0   0.474
0   0.581
0   0.417
0   0.079
0   0.041
0   0.579
0   0.487
0   0.532
0   0.255
0   0.556
0   0.191
0   0.215
0   0.27
0   0.559
0   0.069
0   0.75
0   0.321
0   0.455
0   0.153
0   0.076
0   0.423
0   0.334
0   0.27
0   0.457
0   0.42
1   0.149
1   0.084
1   0.118
1   0.204
1   0.352
1   0.27
1   0.028
1   0.051
1   0.334
1   0.064
1   0.364
1   0.146
1   0.15
1   0.128
1   0.677
1   0.087
1   0.113
1   0.496
1   0.27
1   0.087
1   0.069
1   0.048
1   0.147
1   0.581
1   0.25
0   0.499039
0   0.160928
0   0.300877
0   0.441945
0   0.457
0   0.308663
0   0.134503
0   0.329045
0   0.0978461
0   0.34092
0   0.182607
0   0.210408
0   0.101455
0   0.387889
0   0.21298
0   0.2772
0   0.108788
0   0.0916171
0   0.256354
0   0.609318
0   0.517059
0   0.238948
0   0.107597
0   0.141816
0   0.288725
0   0.104569
0   0.465725
0   0.61839
0   0.333287
0   0.30421
0   0.352555
0   0.0990847
0   0.122333
0   0.462303
0   0.261282
0   0.551918
0   0.130356
0   0.092168
0   0.147923
0   0.384127
0   0.307815
0   0.636982
0   0.455577
0   0.320379
0   0.391365
0   0.41054
0   0.0883434
0   0.0718396
0   0.275106
0   0.634415
0   0.403165
0   0.182067
0   0.064
0   0.103
0   0.076
0   0.112
0   0.514
0   0.677
0   0.298
0   0.513
0   0.152
0   0.179
0   0.485
0   0.57
0   0.242
0   0.084
0   0.496
0   0.374
0   0.472
0   0.513
0   0.016
0   0.162
0   0.337
0   0.308
0   0.581
0   0.443
0   0.27
0   0.316
1   0.01
1   0.047
1   0.314
1   0.053
1   0.53
1   0.152
1   0.514
1   0.217
1   0.462
1   0.359
1   0.453
1   0.415
1   0.321
1   0.327
1   0.352
1   0.066
1   0.0731183
1   0.038658
1   0.246056
1   0.0367594
1   0.250052
1   0.045
1   0.0213815
1   0.134981
1   0.110564
1   0.280861
0   0.171486
0   0.213024
0   0.494228
0   0.227073
0   0.292089
0   0.42622
0   0.08547
0   0.329002
0   0.238219
0   0.139873
0   0.140293
0   0.129252
0   0.673
0   0.18236
0   0.0863466
0   0.2965
0   0.153781
0   0.11698
0   0.147802
0   0.255003
0   0.171924
0   0.395025
0   0.426824
0   0.0725817
0   0.0922318
0   0.321184
0   0.160056
0   0.465388
0   0.0830692
0   0.138164
0   0.66248
0   0.28919
0   0.127184
0   0.672319
0   0.273915
0   0.274922
0   0.199821
0   0.313002
0   0.245132
0   0.130502
0   0.134067
0   0.318106
0   0.101821
0   0.379408
0   0.633172
0   0.188568
0   0.576171
0   0.167011
0   0.108279
0   0.269696
0   0.447
0   0.224
0   0.297
0   0.172
0   0.053
0   0.056
0   0.659
0   0.04
0   0.088
0   0.307
0   0.18
0   0.53
0   0.358
0   0.229
0   0.214
0   0.733
0   0.678
0   0.171
0   0.429
0   0.336
0   0.374
0   0.707
0   0.095
0   0.581
0   0.1
0   0.556
1   0.527863
1   0.0954031
1   0.0917822
1   0.180745
1   0.127418
1   0.331459
1   0.192092
1   0.134105
1   0.299971
1   0.151696
1   0.198835
1   0.0586442
1   0.170819
1   0.0443812
1   0.114581
1   0.0396201
1   0.0920748
1   0.128747
1   0.248526
1   0.0745064
1   0.0498816
1   0.030139
1   0.0315029
1   0.561851
1   0.248531
1   0.048036
0   0.0934189
0   0.260005
0   0.138785
0   0.222089
0   0.275293
0   0.376301
0   0.120048
0   0.142064
0   0.140965
0   0.1977
0   0.0327019
0   0.256466
0   0.380596
0   0.130867
0   0.27045
0   0.186554
0   0.0417732
0   0.166857
0   0.138238
0   0.294624
0   0.0640384
0   0.262783
0   0.159907
0   0.114941
0   0.373715
0   0.369551
0   0.610447
0   0.161292
0   0.18475
0   0.188318
0   0.227243
0   0.266968
0   0.317873
0   0.18678
0   0.159872
0   0.464529
0   0.0683459
0   0.17457
0   0.124066
0   0.134363
0   0.105031
0   0.258503
0   0.50318
0   0.398564
0   0.253605
0   0.0924549
0   0.459214
0   0.37779
0   0.423409
0   0.258992
0   0.099
0   0.237
0   0.471
0   0.329
0   0.206
0   0.04
0   0.313
0   0.097
0   0.095
0   0.128
0   0.447
0   0.471
0   0.085
0   0.145
0   0.457
0   0.192
0   0.071
0   0.497
0   0.06
0   0.113
0   0.072
0   0.265
0   0.161
0   0.14
0   0.42
0   0.235
1   0.0380548
1   0.163722
1   0.236318
1   0.181422
1   0.0564229
1   0.440888
1   0.163106
1   0.0305579
1   0.234902
1   0.0231549
1   0.499566
1   0.0489939
1   0.151815
1   0.110802
1   0.161408
1   0.357252
1   0.109732
1   0.147189
1   0.0457421
1   0.0506764
1   0.368286
1   0.225774
1   0.141402
1   0.0613732
1   0.0584686
1   0.0732126
0   0.074218
0   0.414306
0   0.357649
0   0.0787495
0   0.133315
0   0.402939
0   0.458143
0   0.513628
0   0.369206
0   0.114458
0   0.321146
0   0.301131
0   0.035064
0   0.383734
0   0.376885
0   0.195077
0   0.248111
0   0.159997
0   0.190945
0   0.390668
0   0.220731
0   0.210318
0   0.484851
0   0.0783254
0   0.242972
0   0.116302
0   0.336361
0   0.119856
0   0.630317
0   0.771343
0   0.773017
0   0.468167
0   0.107114
0   0.152301
0   0.460471
0   0.187254
0   0.30811
0   0.171004
0   0.381257
0   0.325415
0   0.371989
0   0.156949
0   0.105421
0   0.165772
0   0.105301
0   0.289966
0   0.24644
0   0.623244
0   0.376608
0   0.153546
0   0.095
0   0.471
0   0.069
0   0.595
0   0.499
0   0.13
0   0.098
0   0.243
0   0.556
0   0.13
0   0.346
0   0.597
0   0.051
0   0.295
0   0.789
0   0.344
0   0.485
0   0.471
0   0.059
0   0.676
0   0.528
0   0.581
0   0.083
0   0.53
0   0.513
0   0.462
1   0.279584
1   0.0829043
1   0.0820136
1   0.165237
1   0.41255
1   0.49425
1   0.0323492
1   0.236546
1   0.0440709
1   0.110593
1   0.1594
1   0.0669509
1   0.0544058
1   0.0690369
1   0.0843828
1   0.0734309
1   0.0552424
1   0.0846833
1   0.1358
1   0.0869965
1   0.345526
1   0.087353
1   0.0484685
1   0.640354
1   0.0382975
1   0.317377
0   0.302771
0   0.409004
0   0.134815
0   0.249468
0   0.148964
0   0.525877
0   0.357133
0   0.296977
0   0.532913
0   0.406251
0   0.229567
0   0.121607
0   0.10691
0   0.173965
0   0.0352168
0   0.228672
0   0.0387207
0   0.094927
0   0.388997
0   0.615013
0   0.484827
0   0.193353
0   0.187652
0   0.399581
0   0.288581
0   0.422332
0   0.235464
0   0.361755
0   0.165823
0   0.382025
0   0.454439
0   0.117501
0   0.583703
0   0.79541
0   0.270634
0   0.0929322
0   0.622777
0   0.389252
0   0.101031
0   0.129959
0   0.409462
0   0.340361
0   0.207414
0   0.315491
0   0.467678
0   0.134645
0   0.0591025
0   0.329735
0   0.22174
0   0.61266
0   0.246
0   0.059
0   0.159
0   0.305
0   0.401
0   0.367
0   0.226
0   0.305
0   0.462
0   0.455
0   0.226
0   0.579
0   0.36
0   0.662
0   0.707
0   0.536
0   0.303
0   0.095
0   0.083
0   0.235
0   0.429
0   0.472
0   0.487
0   0.477
0   0.286
0   0.084
1   0.0783283
1   0.176506
1   0.04887
1   0.0869539
1   0.087
1   0.186845
1   0.148847
1   0.0407017
1   0.0773003
1   0.322769
1   0.133622
1   0.0486399
1   0.165149
1   0.0631825
1   0.526216
1   0.270059
1   0.171065
1   0.21778
1   0.504645
1   0.234726
1   0.0407718
1   0.0211361
1   0.123052
1   0.51742
1   0.332244
1   0.010902
0   0.147953
0   0.421645
0   0.138002
0   0.0561383
0   0.457
0   0.142435
0   0.0415891
0   0.457
0   0.182079
0   0.441678
0   0.116248
0   0.245537
0   0.119357
0   0.202454
0   0.338576
0   0.075427
0   0.184856
0   0.242849
0   0.236672
0   0.240706
0   0.0335897
0   0.0631483
0   0.301717
0   0.171068
0   0.102062
0   0.470175
0   0.616654
0   0.656733
0   0.221006
0   0.459261
0   0.150705
0   0.320793
0   0.369289
0   0.239808
0   0.2786
0   0.517987
0   0.463495
0   0.685939
0   0.260091
0   0.249229
0   0.663916
0   0.134539
0   0.363797
0   0.299316
0   0.154111
0   0.254985
0   0.195693
0   0.537799
0   0.601339
0   0.422757"""

data = data.replace('\n',',')
data = data.replace('   ',',')
data = data.replace(',,',',')
data = data.replace(' ','')
split_data = data.split(",")

label_list = []
data_list = []

for x in range(0,len(split_data)):
  if(x % 2 == 0):
    label_list.append(split_data[x])
  else:
    data_list.append(split_data[x])

for index in range(0,len(label_list)):
  label_list[index] = int(label_list[index])

for index in range(0,len(data_list)):
  data_list[index] = float(data_list[index])

labels = label_list
scores = data_list
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(labels,scores,pos_label = 1)
a1 = auc(tpr,fpr)
plt.plot(tpr,fpr)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]